# I am creating shopify app,and i need to filter the customers from particular customergroup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am using the following API to get Customer group. ShopifyAPI::CustomerGroup. I got customer group names and id but i am not able to retrive the customers for particular customer group.Kindly suggest some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Customer groups is not a valid Shopify API resource or an endpoint. Instead, try to get the customers based on field values listed here - [Customer API](https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/customer).

It'd help much if your grouping is based on certain conditions that are easy to extract from API endpoints.

Comment: If am try to check that coditions based on customergroup means, everytime the customers will be checked.if customer limit is high means what we do.